# Error in my code: Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "("

Tags: sql

```sql
$ CREATE TABLE `2021.dates_times` (
    ride_id STRING NOT NULL,
    start_hour TIME NOT NULL,
    start_day INT NOT NULL,
    start_month INT NOT NULL,
    end_hour TIME NOT NULL,
    end_day INT NOT NULL,
    end_month INT NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY (ride_id)
)$
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need a comma at the end of the line before `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 1):

You have left a comma before primary key.Your code should be

`CREATE TABLE 2021.dates_times (  ride_id STRING NOT NULL,  start_hour TIME NOT NULL,  start_day INT NOT NULL,  start_month INT NOT NULL,  end_hour TIME NOT NULL,  end_day INT NOT NULL,  end_month INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ride_id) )`